# How do I plot the number of instances over time?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get over the basics of creating a histogram or data.frame that will allow me to visualize occurrences within a time period or from start to end. Here's what I'm working with:

It would be a manufacturing plant that operates over this series of months: 201501 201502 201503 201504 201505 201506 201507 201508 201509 201510 201511 201512

and it produces the following number of vehicles over these 12 months: 529 450 700 673 723 743 450 710 632 460 580 652

I've tried the hist function and it gave an error saying "argument 3 matches multiple formal arguments.

When I tried using: plot(months, vehicles), the data points were almost vertical because it wasn't being read as actual months, but rather treated as numerical data i.e. 201500  201550  201600.

Comment: `plot(months, vehicles)`

Comment: YearMonth <- ts(Defects, start=decimal_date(ymd("2015-01-01")), frequency = 365.25/12) I trying doing this to list the months by month but R told me "Could not find decimal_date"

Comment: frequency is 12 and not 365.25/12

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert your months column to a valid date format and than you can just plot it using a `barplot` instead of `histogram` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(months = c(201501, 201502, 201503, 201504, 201505, 201506, 201507, 201508, 201509, 201510, 201511, 201512),
                vehicles = c(529, 450, 700, 673, 723, 743, 450, 710, 632, 460, 580, 652))

df$months_new <- format(as.Date(paste(as.character(df$months), '01'), '%Y%m%d'), '%b')

barplot(vehicles ~ months_new, data = df, xlab = "Months")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>